# Asp.net post method trigger

Tags: asp.net, paypal

Currently Im devloping a order page where customer choose the start level and end level, and it would calculate the price because It trigger the "selectindexchange" for the dropdownlist.

The payment method is paypal, which uses the method="post", but whenever I select the level it will just trigger the paypal "buy" button and direct the page to paypal payment page:(

Comment: Make sure if `page_load` has a check that if page posted back and trigger `buy`, then you need to modify that to do only when `buy` button is clicked.

Comment: No code? Debug it - it will surely show you the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you need to be sure that auto post back property is false for that controls so you require submit button to post it.

Example / Help : [autoPostBack](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/prop_webcontrol_textbox_autopostback.asp)

Also use this in page_load

```
    if(!isPostBack){

}
     else{

}
```

which checks the page has load first time or after any post back.